# Setting up Windows Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2008 on a VPS

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vps, remote-access, sql-server-2008-r2, asp.net-mvc

I wish to deploy trusted apps in a secure way.

I got one empty VPS (with no operating system). But I don't know how to install Windows Server 2008 R2 (Enterprise/Datacenter) and SQL server 2008 (Enterprise) on it.

The main purpose is to deploy ASP.Net v4 MVC 2 and XBAP Apps + LINQ and also use SQL Server for my Windows application with remote access.

Also, could anyone direct me to some resources that would show me know to setup a Windows domain, configure IP settings, install and configure OS and features etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've said this on previous answers and I'm going to say it here: I suggest you get someone who knows what they are doing as this is wayyyy too much for some people on a FaQ site to walk you through.

I was under the impression that a VPS always comes with some sort of OS on it and then you could go from there. Is it not possible to contact the VPS hosting company?

I'd love to set up a VPS from scratch but ultimately if I don't know what I'm doing then I'm going to ask for help. Once you've got the OS and everything installed you'd be better off coming back here and asking (or searching) for how to lockdown a server, best way for upates, naming conventions and such. Good luck.

Comment: because of my budget is limited.. that why i need to do it all manually -.- my VPS is just cost me $40 and he do ask me to provide my own OS and DB...then everything need to maintain by myself~